# Scroll clipping in Android web view

Tags: android, cordova, scroll, android-webview

I have a scrollable area (`overflow: auto;`) inside a PhoneGap app webview which exhibits weird clipping areas when scrolled (it seems to re-render sections of the page slowly in a grid pattern). I can't figure out what is causing the stuttering.

The scrollable region has a hardware transform applied (`-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`), and `hardwareAccelerated="true"` is in the manifest. I'm observing the problem on Android 4.2.2.

Comment: I have found that this is still a limitation based on hardware/os build config. In Android 4.3 this seems to be better, but still not perfect. Have you tried using a library like iScroll? It adds more code, but it's been a more reliable scrolling solution for the projects I have produced.

Comment: Unfortunately, iScroll solves the clipping problem, but has such a poor frame rate I'd rather have the clipping. Seems like the Android phones just can't keep up with scrolling the page.

Comment: I agree. Have you tried the "useTransform: false," param with iScroll? I was able to get better performance using that, but still not perfect.